# Retrieving Data From a complex associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Im working with data submitted from a jotform widget -when I run print_r($_POST) I get the following data

```
Array ( 
[formID] => 40923773875567 
[q1_clickTo] => Country: UNITED STATES
Province: Kentucky
Latitude: 37.568694
Longitude: -84.29632229999999
[website] => [simple_spc] => 40923773875567-40923773875567 
)
```

I need help in retrieving the country, province, latitude, longitude and website [simple_spc] data

please help - thank you

Comment: What is problem use indexed access like $a['website']['simple_spc'] ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that your data in `s1_clickTo` is a string.  I suggest getting your data in another format, because now you have to parse this yourself.

I would use `explode()` on new line `\n` (or `\r\n` depending on the actual format), and then for each key/value, explode on `:` or use RegEx to match.

Answer (score 0):

Access them in this way..

```
echo $_POST['q1_clickTo'];
echo $_POST['website']['simple_spc'];
```

Answer (score 0):

May be its better to write some parser with closures like this?

```
$a = array(
   'formID' => '40923773875567',
   'q1_clickTo' => "Country: UNITED STATES
Province: Kentucky
Latitude: 37.568694
Longitude: -84.29632229999999",
   'website' => array(
      'simple_spc' => '40923773875567-40923773875567'
   )
);

$trim  = function($v) { return trim($v); };
$float = function($v) { return (float) $v; };

$mapping = array(
   'spc' => array('website', function($v) { return $v['simple_spc']; }),
   'data' => array('q1_clickTo', function($v) {
      $data   = explode("\n", $v);
      $result = [];
      foreach ($data as $line) {
          $parts = explode(':', $line);
          $result[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
      }
      return $result;
   }),
   'country' => array('Country', $trim),
   'longitude' => array('Longitude', $float),
   'latitude' => array('Latitude', $float),
   'province' => array('Province', $trim)
);

$result = [];
foreach ($mapping as $key => $value) {
   $info = $a[$value[0]];
   $info = $value[1]($info);
   if (!is_array($info)) {
       $result[$key] = $info;
   } else {
      foreach ($info as $infoKey => $infoValue) {
          $a[$infoKey] = $infoValue;
      }
   }
}
var_export($result);
```

Working example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04f28278bb00b3ca0372d85a837537a2552bc248